# How to prove that $f(x) = x^ε - \log x$ is $\infty$ when $x\to\infty$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm trying to prove that the function $x^ε$ is "bigger" than $\log x$ when $x\to\infty$, for every $ε>0$.

Or to put it in a more formal way:

For every $ε>0$, there exists a constant $N$ for which all $x>N$ the following is true:

$x^ε > \log x$

I don't believe that the base of the log is important for this one, but just in case, it is 2.

Comment: Try putting both sides on the exponent.

Comment: Try using the ideas from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181004/, and remember that $\log{x}=-\log{(1/x)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: Show $\dfrac{x^{\epsilon}}{\log x} \to +\infty$ by L'hospitale rule.

Comment: Awesome timing, I just did. But I think I might have a small problem with this. The base of the log is 2. Is $lg'(x)$ still $1/x$?

Comment: @Tom no, only the natural logarithm has derivative $1/x$ hence why it's natural. Log base two obeys the following equality $\log_2 x=\frac{\log x}{\log2}$ and hence taking derivative gives $(\log_2x)'=\frac1{x\log2}$